# How to reduce duplicate Anchor Texts when Sourcing/Citing Websites

Tags: seo, anchor, anchor-text

I'm new to web-developement and SEO. I'm creating a news website that writes articles about the latest video-game news.
On some articles I include the source at the bottom of the page:

```
<a href="www.example.com">Source</a>
```

When I've been using SEO Tools to check the optimisation of my site. Unfortunately they regularly report:

> Some Anchor Texts are used more than once

So, how can I source or cite a website at the end of articles, without creating SEO issues, or duplicating Anchor Texts? (assuming this is actually the issue.)

Comment: I don't know whether "Source" could actually cause SEO issues, but have you considered quoting the title of the article you're sourcing? Something like: "Source: [Article Title - Website Name](https://example.com/)"

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Good idea. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

> Some Anchor Texts are used more than once

This is not a problem in this case.

SEO tools try to simplify complex problems. This is a case where they missed the opportunity to ignore an edge case.

Duplicate anchor texts are mainly a problem with internal links. If you link with "iPhone" to 10 different URLs, that does not send a clear signal to Google which of your pages is most relevant for the term "iPhone".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I understand. So going off topic a little, for internal links, should the same page always be linked with the same anchor text. even from different pages? Or is it only an issue when the same Text links to different pages? Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: The second part. Linking with the same text to different pages is an issue. Linking with different text to the same page is normal.

Comment: Thank you Malte. I appreciate you clarifying that.